# glsl qt shader program

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Can you help me write the correct shader program(glsl) for QT painterPath adaptation to SceneGraph. The geometry of the node triangulated ok, but i can't write correct shader material for hatched brush style.

```
1. pathNode.cpp

#include <QtQuick/QSGSimpleMaterialShader>
#include <QtQuick/QSGTexture>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickWindow>

#include <private/qtriangulator_p.h>
#include <QPainterPath>

#include "pathNode.h"

#define TEXTURE_SIZE 64

struct BrushMaterial
{
    ~BrushMaterial() {
        delete texture;
    }

    QColor          color;
    QSGTexture*     texture;
};

class BrushShader : public QSGSimpleMaterialShader<BrushMaterial>
{
    QSG_DECLARE_SIMPLE_SHADER(BrushShader, BrushMaterial)

public:
    BrushShader() : 
        id_color(-1), 
        id_texture(-1),
        id_textureSize(-1)
    {
        setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shaders/brush.vsh");
        setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shaders/brush.fsh");
    }

    QList<QByteArray> attributes() const
    {
        return QList<QByteArray>() << "aVertex" << "aTexCoord";
    }

    void updateState(const BrushMaterial *m, const BrushMaterial *)
    {
        // Set the color
        program()->setUniformValue(id_color, m->color);

        // Bind the texture and set program to use texture unit 0 (the default)
        m->texture->bind();

        // Then set the texture size so we can adjust the texture coordinates accordingly in the
        // vertex shader..
        QSize s = m->texture->textureSize();
        program()->setUniformValue(id_textureSize, QSizeF(1.0 / s.width(), 1.0 / s.height()));
    }

    void resolveUniforms()
    {
        id_texture = program()->uniformLocation("texture");
        id_textureSize = program()->uniformLocation("textureSize");
        id_color = program()->uniformLocation("color");

        // We will only use texture unit 0, so set it only once.
        program()->setUniformValue(id_texture, 0);
    }

private:
    int id_color;
    int id_texture;
    int id_textureSize;
};

PathNode::PathNode(QSGTexture* texture,const QColor& color)
    : m_geometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_TexturedPoint2D(), 0, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_INT)
{
    setGeometry(&m_geometry);
    m_geometry.setDrawingMode(GL_TRIANGLES);

    QSGSimpleMaterial<BrushMaterial>* m = BrushShader::createMaterial();

    m->state()->texture = texture;
    m->state()->color = color;
    m->setFlag(QSGMaterial::Blending);

    setMaterial(m);
    setFlag(OwnsMaterial, true);
}

void PathNode::update(const QPainterPath& path)
{
    const QTriangleSet triangles{ qTriangulate(path) };

    // Fill vertex buffer
    m_geometry.allocate(triangles.vertices.size() / 2, triangles.indices.size());
    QSGGeometry::TexturedPoint2D *vertex = m_geometry.vertexDataAsTexturedPoint2D();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_geometry.vertexCount(); ++i)
        vertex[i].set(triangles.vertices.at(2 * i), triangles.vertices.at(2 * i + 1), 1, 0);

    // Fill index buffer
    uint *indices = m_geometry.indexDataAsUInt();
    if (triangles.indices.type() != QVertexIndexVector::UnsignedInt)
        qFatal("Unexpected geometry index type");
    memcpy(indices, triangles.indices.data(), triangles.indices.size() * sizeof(*indices));

    markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry);
}
```

2.PathNode.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QSGGeometryNode>

class PathNode : public QSGGeometryNode
{
    QSGGeometry             m_geometry;

public:
    PathNode(QSGTexture* texture, const QColor& color);

    void update(const QPainterPath& path);
};
```

3.brush.vsh

```
attribute highp vec4 aVertex;
attribute highp vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
uniform highp vec2 textureSize;

varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
varying lowp vec2 vShadeCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = qt_Matrix * aVertex;
    vTexCoord = aVertex.xy * textureSize;
    vShadeCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

4. brush.fsh

   ```
   uniform sampler2D texture;
   uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
   uniform lowp vec4 color;

   varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

   void main()
   {
       lowp vec4 shade = texture2D(texture, vTexCoord) ;
       lowp vec4 c = vec4(color.xyz * shade.xyz, 1.0);
       gl_FragColor = c * qt_Opacity;
   }
   ```

The main trouble is what the painted hatches with colored background, but i want to have transparent background.

link to github code: [painterPath_QSGNode](https://github.com/nik13513513/painterPath_QSGNode)

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a transparent color to the item.

In main.cpp, at line 50, change:

```
fillBrush.setColor(Qt::red);
```

to:

```
fillBrush.setColor(Qt::transparent);
```

Comment: This is the result I got: [imgur](https://imgur.com/h0IY3jk). Or I missunderstand what you want to obtain?

Comment: I need fill the path with the red cross-lines, but without background. right now i have the red fill, with lighter cross-lines.

Comment: Sorry can you make a mockup picture of the result you want?

Comment: the main target is fill the node like QBrush style.